# Oracle 10g Create a View passing in a parameter

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am have been searching but I have not been able to find a satisfactory solution where I can pass a parameter to a view.

What I am trying to do is to call a view saved in Oracle 10g passing in a date via NHibernate, which sounds simple enough, but I am reading that passing parameters to view is not so. So, I am unless I am being misled, can someone please advise me whether this is possible and how; or should I do this as a Stored Procedure?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE aView AS VIEW
 SELECT col1,
        col2,
        col3,
 FROM someTable
 WHERE col4 <= TO_DATE('somePassInDate', 'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

The above is the sort of query I want to run. I don't hibernate to create this query.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share some example of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Look now for update

Comment: Look into pipelined table functions: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions

Comment: Why not simply apply that condition when selecting _from_ the view?

Comment: There is a problem with pipelined-table-functions as they are inefficient and could take a while to return any rows. This query is part of a housekeeping query where every night it will return thousands of rows. This is why I have taken it away from nhibernate as it is inefficient

Answer (score 0):

> There is a problem with pipelined-table-functions as they are
>   inefficient and could take a while to return any rows. This query is
>   part of a housekeeping query where every night it will return
>   thousands of rows. This is why I have taken it away from nhibernate as
>   it is inefficient

This is wrong. Pipelined functions are more efficient than `table functions`. The reason being:

> Pipelining allows rows to be passed out of table functions as they are
>   produced, rather than waiting for whole collections to be produced
>   before the results are returned.  The outcome is a reduction in the
>   time taken for the first rows to be produced and a reduction in the
>   total amount of memory consumed by the table function.

You can read an elaborative example here [Pipelined Functions](http://dba-oracle.com/plsql/t_plsql_pipelining.htm)

However not sure what is your need, but you can create a dynamic block or Procedure to get your requirement. On execution of the below block it would prompt for a input date.

```
DECLARE
   v_sql    VARCHAR2 (1000);
   v_date   DATE := :v_date;
BEGIN
   v_sql := q'[CREATE OR REPLACE aView AS VIEW
          SELECT col1,
          col2,
           col3,
          FROM someTable
          WHERE col4 <= TO_DATE(':somePassInDate', 'dd/mm/yyyy')]';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql USING v_date;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way how to "customize" output from a via is to use system context. It is something like a global variable in a SQL engine.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5002.htm

```
CREATE OR REPLACE aView AS VIEW
 SELECT col1,
        col2,
        col3,
 FROM someTable
 WHERE col4 <= TO_DATE(SYS_CONTEXT ('MY_CONTEXT', 'MY_CTX_VARIABLE') , 'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

Where you will find HOWTO set value for a context variable:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114252/oracle-how-do-i-set-a-context-variable

IMHO it is not worth of trying, you will need privilege granted "CREATE ANY SYSTEM CONTEXT". If you use hibernate, you should not combine it with advanced Oracle stuff.